# Visual bug on 'Activity' tab on user page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The button 'all' overlays the border on this page.  See the screenshot below.  This happens in Chrome, Firefox and Safari on Mac OS X 10.6.6

[image]

Comment: i'm looking into this

Comment: this has been fixed. could you mark it as accepted. Also check your other bug reports too. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix will be in the next deployment