# Visual bugs on user panel with new Lion style

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

This [old visual](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318/visual-bug-on-activity-tab-on-user-page) glitch seems to have returned:

It's in the responses tab, I also see it on the activity and reputation tabs. (at least for my userid).

[image: visual bug]

Comment: I see this in both Firefox 4 and Safari 5.1.

Comment: chrome as well. It's basically everywhere modern, that's why I didn't bother to mention the browser.

Answer (score 1):

the fix will be in the next deployment.